# Multidimensional array undefined index problem

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am getting a multidimensional array from an HTML form. When I want to get a single value, e.g.

```
$chapters = $_POST["chapters"];

echo $chapters[0]["title"];
```

it says *undefined index `title`*.

When I print the array, it shows as

```
Array
(
    [chapters] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    ['title'] => this is title
                    ['text'] => this is text
                    ['photo'] => this is photo source
                    ['photo_caption'] => photo caption
                )

        )
)
```

Comment: (a) Which array are you printing? `$_POST` or `$chapters`? (b) If this is the exact output, why are the string keys one time in quotes (e.g. `['title']`) and the other time without quotes (`[chapters]`) ? `print_r` never prints string keys with quotes, so you must have manipulated the output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your comments, the problem seemed to be following:

`print_r` never prints quotes for string keys. If you have not manipulated the output somehow, then it can only mean that the single quotes are actually part of the key.

This should work:

```
echo $chapters[0]["'title'"];
```

but better you fix the keys.

From your comment:

> the problem was that i was using single quotes (`name="chapter[0]['photo_caption']"`) in html form, corrected to `name="chapter[0][photo_caption]"` solved the problem

Answer (score 4):

According to your output, you should be using `$chapters["chapters"][0]["title"]`.

Note that you have 3 nested arrays in your output, therefore you'll need to go 3 levels deep to get your value.

Comment: $chapters["chapter**s**"][0]["title"] :)

Comment: thanks Felix Kling, the problem was that i was using single quotes (name="chapter[0]['photo_caption']") in html form, corrected to name="chapter[0][photo_caption]" solved the problem, many many thanks

Comment: @Shoaib: Ah, so the they keys literally contained single quotes? That was tricky...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I faced the same problem. Then I realized, I was doing wrong with the keys. 
Actually, I was using the quote while naming the form elements as an array

Example-

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name= userprogramscholarship[$user->id]['checkstatus'] value= $val />";
```

I corrected and removed quotes as below

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name= userprogramscholarship[$user->id][checkstatus] value= $val />";
```

It was minor mistake. Removed quotes and it worked then.